# Self Compare of transaction table to find values

Tags: mysql, string-comparison, self-join

I have a mysql table with the following fields

`Transaction_id`, `toy_id`, `toy_name`, `Quantity_sold`, `Date_sold`.

The question I am trying to answer is: What toys were sold today that were not sold yesterday. I understand this is very vague, so please feel free to make any assumptions that need to be made to help just write it down too plz and thank you!!

Comment: So what have you done to try and solve this yourself? We're happy to help, but only for those who've TRIED doing it themselves. we're not here to do your job for you.

Comment: have you a list of toys for check which are sold and which no?

Comment: Marc B, Sorry for not putting up my code, I did that on purpose so as not to steer the answers in a specific direction. I understand your point and do not want to take advantage of anybody else's work. thank you for your time.

Comment: I am limited to just using this one table @scaisEdge

Comment: I have posted an asnwer.. hope useful

Answer (score 0):

One method uses aggregation with a `having` clause:

```
select toy_id
from t
where date_sold >= date_sub(curdate(), interval 1 day)
group by toy_id
having date(min(date_sold)) = curdate();
```

The `where` clause limits the data to the past two days.  If the minimum date is today, then no toys were sold yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `not exists` operator to find the toys that were not sold yesterday. E.g.:

```
SELECT toy_id, toy_name
FROM   transactions today
WHERE  date_sold = CURRENT_DATE()
       AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                       FROM   transactions yesterday
                       WHERE  today.toy_id = yesterday.toy_id AND
                              yesterday.date_sold = 
                              today.date_solde - INTERVAL 1 DAY);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a not in  and subselect

```
  Select Transaction_id, toy_id, toy_name, Quantity_sold, Date_sold
  from my_table  
  where to_id not in (
    select T toy_id 
    from my_table  
    where Date_sold = date(date_sub(now(), INTERVAL 1 day))
  );
```